# Sed how to extract text between two tags but including it

Tags: sed, regular-expression, html

I am trying to figure out why this command is not working for me:

```
sed -n -e '/<a href=\(.*\)>/,/<\/a>/p' text.html
```

On text.html we have something like...

```
<somestupidstuff> <a href='teste'> teste </a> </somestupidstuff>
```

The desired output is:

```
<a href='teste'> teste </a>
```

But what I get is:

```
<somestupidstuff> <a href='teste'> teste </a> </somestupidstuff>
```

Maybe I am not fully understanding the regex.

Comment: What your `sed` expression is doing is printing all the _lines_ between the matches of `/<a href=\(.*\)>/` and of `/<\/a>/`.  If this is a well formed XML document, you may want to look into using an XML parser instead, such as `xmlstarlet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier to use `grep` for your case. E.g. this way:

```
grep -o '<a href=[^<]*<\/a>'
```

In case there are `<` between `<a href>..</a>` you might want to try this instead:

```
grep -o '<a href=.*<\/a>'
```

However pay attention that it might return a data you don't expect for strings where you have multiple `<a href=...</a>` occurrences in the same string.

`sed` doesn't work for you because `/pattern1/,/pattern2/p` instructs `sed` to print all lines between line with `pattern1` to line with `pattern2` (including lines with patterns).

The problem might be solved with `sed` as well, but it depends on `somestupidstuff` content (e.g. whether it's the same in all cases or not, etc)

Comment: It is better but I am still having trouble, I dont see anything like a href beetween the strings, but it is still breaking it for some unknow reason. I will try to be more specific...

Comment: A lot of ocurrencies of <a href=***>  blabla </a> are being ignored the lines are very long like the results of a google search for example, this is giving me some heartaches, but I cant understand why something simple like that can be so unexpected.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini Do you have any additional spaces between `a` and `href`? Do you have multi line entries where `<a` starts on one line and `</a>` ends on another line? (`grep` in a way I posted it doesn't expect multi-line entries)

Comment: ah. you have `<` between `<a href>..</a>' while `grep` doesn't expect it. I'll update the answer.